# Explain why do while loop has not checking the condition?

Tags: c

```
void main () {
    char f;
   do {
        scanf("%c",&f);// input a  character
        printf("%c",f);//output a  character

   }while(f=='y');
}
```

any value is going to end the program even if **y** put is end the program can anyone explain the reason on this program I am stuck at this ..

Comment: Your program seems to work fine.  Perhaps you are confused because you are entering data interactively and have forgotten that `'\n' != 'y'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the new line char in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer)

Comment: What key do you hit after `'y'`?

Answer (score 1):

Other than the `void main()` (the return value of `main` should be `int`) and the failure to check the value returned by `scanf` (if scanf returns 0 and does not assign a value to `f`, then attempting to read a value from the uninitialized `f` is undefined behavior), your program works just fine:

```
$ echo yyyyyabcd | ./a.out; echo
yyyyya
```

However, if you are entering data interactively, you may be entering the input stream `y\ny\n` (hitting enter/return after each `y`), and the program is terminating when it sees the first newline.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when `scanf` gets executed again, it is reading a white space character left in the input stream from the previous input you type.

The simplest solution is to include a whitespace character before the `%c` conversion specifier. Example:

```
scanf(" %c",&f);// input a  character
```

This tells `scanf` to skip leading whitespace.